# Get Text and int Form Mysql and store in a text box

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am making an application witch uses a Browser to show a viral video a week.The url for the video is stored in a my MySQL database online along with an int that shows a counter in the top right hand corner, What I want to do is get the string of text from the MySQL data base and the in and write that information into a text box called Video1 and Counter.

Here is some of my current code:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(Refresh_Rate.Text);
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        try
        {
            string myConnrction = "datasource=************;port=3306;username=*******;password=*******";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnrction);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from sql337069.Youtube where Video1='", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }



            MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter =new MySqlDataAdapter();
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * sql337069.Youtube ;", myConn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
            myConn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MessageBox.Show("Working");
            myConn.Close();


        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Null");
        }
```

So I guess I am looking for is something like `Video1.text += [?]`.

Comment: In which column you store this counter? Little bit unclear what you asking.

Comment: @SonerGönül it is named Video1_count

Comment: So your `select Video1_count sql337069.Youtube` returns only one value?

Comment: @SonerGönül lets just say the id name is Video 1 and the value is a link how would i get that and put it into a textbox in my c# application

Comment: @SonerGönül i will take 3 screenshots of my data base to make it easier to understand 1)http://prntscr.com/3b5uut 2) http://prntscr.com/3b5vr2 3) http://prntscr.com/3b5w4p  sorry if i am being confusing i am new to Mysql

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it would be better for you to grab the columns that you want in your select statement, rather than selecting all column (*).  When you select the ones you want, you know the exact structure of the data that is being returned and you can hold that in a class or structure that you create. say, something like this for example:

```
public struct Video
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Count;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myConnectionString = "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING";
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, VideoName, VideoPlayCount FROM dbo.VideoTable WHERE Id = YOUR_VIDEO_RECORD_ID", myConn);
    Video video = new Video();

    myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    myConn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
    reader.Read();
    video.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
    video.Name = reader.GetString(1);
    video.Count = reader.GetInt32(2);
    myConn.Close();

    string myTextBoxValue = video.Name + " " + video.Count.ToString();
}
```

Using this example would require you to replace the "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING" with the connection string to your database, as well as entering in the correct table name and  table column for the select statement, but other than that, this should get you what you are looking for I believe.  The string "myTextBoxValue" is being assigned the video name and count as requested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thankyou but i am sorry to say i still do not understand

Comment: I have updated the response to include a more elaborate example of what I was trying to describe to you. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thakyou so much i have found a working method my mixing some other code with what you gave you +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

For Me i Have discovered that this method works best But thanks to Kevin for helping me fill in some code.

```
            try
        {
            //Defanitions  
            string myConnrction = "*********;port=3306;username=******;password=******";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnrction);
            MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * sql337069.Youtube;", myConn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string Query = "select * from sql337069.Youtube ;";
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myreader;
            //Defanitions  

            myConn.Open();
            myreader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myreader.GetString("Video2_Refresh");
                Video2_Refresh.Text = sName;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Working");


        }



        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Null");
        }
```

(I am posting this for stack overflow reference Because i could not find much on this subject )